# Can I see the expected future actions on a bill?

Tags: united-states, congress, legislative-process

The Congress.gov site provides with detailed and up-to-date information about bills. However, I fail to find the information about any planned/anticipated actions related to an arbitrary bill, e.g. future hearing in Committees.

**Can I get this information — either on Congress.gov or another U.S. Government site?**

Here's what I mean. Using [S.814 - Ukraine Security Partnership Act of 2021](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/senate-bill/814) as an example because it is of a special interest to me.

As of April/26, this bill has an outstanding amendment by Senate Foreign Relations Committee, so I'm sure there *must be* an anticipated future event for this bill.

[The bill page](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/senate-bill/814) contains "Tracker", but it only shows the bill's past, not the anticipated future events (e.g. hearings or pending amendments).

[image: Bill page]

---

The Committees tab shows past Committees hearings.

[image: Committees tab]

---

And the same with Actions tab; only past Actions are listed.

[image: Actions tab]

Question: is there a possibility get a list of anticipated future events related to a bill?

Comment: An amendment doesn't mean action on it is planned. It could have been added just to kill the bill but I don't know about this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Congress moves at its own pace

Following a bill from introduction through passage can be frustrating. Ultimately, Congress moves at whatever speed it feels like for a given bill. That's why there aren't any future actions listed on Congress.gov. Since the bill in question has been assigned to the Senate Foreign Relations Committee, you can watch [the committee website](https://www.foreign.senate.gov/hearings) to see if there's a hearing coming up. You could also try calling the committee at (202) 224-4651 to see if they have any information on a scheduled action (it's a long shot but the committee has been working on the bill recently so they might have additional info). If you're fortunate enough to have representation in the Senate (as a resident of Washington DC I do not) then you can call your Senator's office to see if they have any additional information.